# Robocopy command is very slow over the network

Tags: robocopy

I am trying to copy near to 2 TB files over the network using robocopy command. But it is really slow and now it's near to more that one day but still files are not copied.

Robocopy "\DC01\Shared Folders" "\FP02\Shared Folders" /E /COPY:DATSOU /R:10 /LOG:C:\Copyresults.txt

Comment: 2 TB? That's going to take awhile. How much has been copied to the destination so far?

Answer (score 5):

You can use /j option, unbuffered I/O. It's suggested for large files and may give you better speed.

Although you haven't used it, /z (restartable switch, to continue copying of file from where it stopped, in case of interruption) may slow down the bit rate.

That's the 2 options I've seen to make a difference in speed using robocopy.

Comment: Thanks - additionally /j /mt seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change R:30 to R:0 so it skips open files and doesn't waste time on the same file it cannot copy.
There are powershell commands to force files to close if that is needed. I don't until final cutover of the file server.
Also recommend put in /XF *.tmp (and any other filter you would like it to skip (i.e. *thumbs.db)